# Using router inside getStaticProps

Tags: next.js

I'm trying to fetch data from an API that varies depending on the URL, trying to do it with withRouter but it seems it won't work inside getStaticProps.

I currently have the following code:

```
export async function getStaticProps({ router }) {
const pageRequest = `http://localhost:3000/api/posts/${router.query.pid}`
const res = await fetch(pageRequest)
const json = await res.json()
return {
    props: {
        json,
    },
}
}
```

It's returning:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'query' of undefined
```

What's the proper way to get the variable in the URL to use inside getStaticProps?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The `getStaticProps` function [primarily runs at build time](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/get-static-props#when-does-getstaticprops-run), so there is no router available.

If the dynamic route looks like `/pages/[pid].js` you can access `pid` at `context.params.pid` as the following:

```
export async function getStaticProps(context) {
  const pid = context.params.pid
  return {
    props: {}, // will be passed to the page component as props
  }
}
```

Keep in mind that using static export with dynamic routes requires `getStaticPaths`. You'd need to specify all possible IDs.

```js
export async function getStaticPaths() {
  return {
    paths: [
      { params: { pid: '1' } },
      { params: { pid: '2' } }
    ],
    fallback: true or false // See the "fallback" section below
  };
}
```

Also, you can't use Next.js API routes of the same project in `getStaticProps` as it's executed at build time without a server running. Instead, you can fetch data directly from the database.

Check out [getStaticProps docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/get-static-props) for more examples and details.

Alternatively, consider [fetching data on the client side](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/client-side).

Comment: The thing is I need it to be static, how can I fetch from mysql and use it with getStaticProps? Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: > Also, you can't call your own API in getStaticProps as it's executed at build time (no server is running). You can fetch data directly from the database without an API call. 

That part actually isn't true. You can call an API with fetch or similar inside `getStaticProps` and then return the response, with or without further processing, to the page as props.

export async function getStaticProps(context) {
    const response = await GraphQLRequest(); // or another async fetch
    return {
        props: response //comes from the API
    }
}

Comment: @i-know-nothing, you can't call  **your own** Next.js API of the same project. There is no server is running during build time.

Comment: Ahhh, got it, you mean like an API route defined inside Next.js. My bad for misunderstanding.

Comment: You can definitely make an API call to fetch and return data in `getStaticProps` method.

Comment: @ConnorLeech, I corrected wording in the answer. It meant - can't call API routes of the same Next.js project. Surely can call any other APIs. Hope its more clear now.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this will work for your situation but if you use can getServerSideProps instead, you can get the query id with the following:

```
export async function getServerSideProps({ query }) {
  const pageRequest = `http://localhost:3000/api/posts/${query.pid}`
  const res = await fetch(pageRequest)
  const json = await res.json()

  return {
    props: {
        json,
    },
  }
}
```

I know that there are different considerations for using either getStaticProps or getServerSideProps but as described by Nikolai in his answer there are many more steps needed to work with getStaticProps in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to solve this problem is to change the architecture of your API.

(I know this may not always be possible or practical) but...

If you change the API so that you don't need to pass it an ID, but instead return all the data in one API call. That way you don't need to use router inside getStaticProps.

Then in your nextjs app you can query the response of the API and by using router inside your component.

I know this is going to depend on how large the data coming back from the API would be, and if you own the API end point and can change it.

Just an idea.